# Do the enemy that appear in arcade game when running out of time have a canonical name?

Tags: terminology, arcade

Basically, several level-based games "back in the day" had a special kind of enemy appearing when playing the same level for too long. Bubble bubble had 
[Baron von Blubba](http://bubblebobble.wikia.com/wiki/Baron_von_Blubba):

[image: Baron von Blubba]

Snow Brothers had a similar one (a weird pumpkin figure spawning invincible ghosts).

Does this kind of enemy have a canonical name? (Like "boss", but it's *not* a boss of course.)

Comment: would a more recent example be the ghost in splunkey?

Comment: Well, I'd say yes. And http://spelunky.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ghost/Classic says `it functions more like Baron von Blubba of the Bubble Bobble series, who operates as an invincible (but avoidable) enforcer of the stage time limit`, so yes :)

Comment: thought so I don't know of any names for those kinds of enemy types though.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no canonical name for them.

However, I somewhat like the term **Chase Boss** this GiantBomb user has come up with, although it does not strictly limit the term to enemies appearing due to time constraints: http://www.giantbomb.com/baron-von-blubba/3005-10958/forums/the-mentop-tento-ten-best-chase-bosses-504317/

It's also worth noting that 1980 arcade game Berzerk probably featured the first enemy of this kind, fittingly named **Evil Otto**.

Comment: Wow I'd forgotten about that.  +1 for the historical reference.

Answer (score 5):

I usually hear this referred to as the **Soft Timer** *(I realize the enemy itself is not a timer, but this is still what people call it)*.

"Soft Timer" is opposed to a *"Hard Timer"*, which causes you to lose immediately when it runs out.

Examples:

- [Here](http://www.reddit.com/r/vita/comments/1lm1p5/so_is_spelunky_worth_it/cc0oh2i) and [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/239350/discussions/0/864975632396707556) various users call the ghost in Spelunky the soft timer
- [Here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/212680/discussions/0/648814300408711696) some users refer to the Rebel Fleet in FTL as the soft timer
- [Here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5836324954#5) someone refers fire spreading during the Butcher in Diablo 3 as a soft timer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they have a collective name, but I like to name them `Arcade Enrage`.

The name comes from World of Warcraft when battling a boss for too long. The boss would then **enrage**, increasing damage by a lot, and *death is inevitable*.

Somewhat the same goes for those characters.